# How to get specific rows in CSV using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

How can I get all data from specific rows in csv file using Pandas.

My goal is to get the data from all the rows which ends with *05*.

The data is now listed with year and month like this:

```
1989-01
1989-02
1989-03
1989-04
1989-05
```

...

And so on.

So I want to get data from all the years, but only for the month of May (05).

If I set this data to index, is it maybe easier?

Comment: Assuming you are able to import the csv into a dataframe you can use substrings.

df= pd.read_csv('xxxxx.csv')
df_may = df[df['**columnnamehere**'].str.endswith('05')]

Answer (score 1):

For this, you can filter your data in a new dataframe using *endswith*, like this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Change the below file name with your CSV file name
df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv')

# Create a Boolean mask
mask = df['your_column'].str.endswith('05')

# Use the above created mask to filter the data in the new dataframe
filter_df = df[mask]

# Display the filtered dataframe
print(filtered_df)
```